# Probability, poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Can anyone help with the following question?

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be independent Poisson random variables with parameter $\lambda$. What is the mass function of $X_1+\ldots+X_n$?

Comment: What do you know?  What have you tried?

Comment: @kimchilover To address you second question, he/she has *not* even tried searching "sum of indepedent Poisson $\downarrow$". Otherwise,
 he/she will find the [classic proof on Pr$\infty$fWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Independent_Poisson_Random_Variables_is_Poisson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
  P(X_1+ X_2 =k) &= \sum_{i = 0}^k P(X_1+ X_2 = k, X_1 = i)\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^k P(X_2 = k-i , X_1 =i)\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^k P(X_2 = k-i)P(X_1=i)\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^k e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k-i}}{(k-i)!}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^i}{i!}\\
   &= e^{-2\lambda}\frac 1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}\lambda^{k-i}\lambda^i\\
   &= \frac{(2\lambda)^k}{k!}e^{-2\lambda}
\end{align}

Now let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^n{X_j}$. We can easily prove that $S_n\sim\operatorname{Po}(n\lambda)$ using a similar approach.